# Show $\mathbb{E}\left[\left|\sum_{i=1}^n X_iY_i\right|\right] \leq 2\mathbb{E}\left[\left|\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i\right|\right]$

Tags: probability, inequality, random-variables

In Exercise 5.9 of [this book](https://www.hse.ru/data/2016/11/24/1113029206/Concentration%20inequalities.pdf), it is stated that if $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ are independent random variables with finite variance and let $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ be independent Rademacher random variables (i.e., $\mathbb{P}[X_i = 1] = \mathbb{P}[X_i = -1] = 1/2$ for all $i$). Suppose that $(X_i)$ and $(Y_i)$ are independent as well, then
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\left|\sum_{i=1}^n X_iY_i\right|\right] \leq 2\mathbb{E}\left[\left|\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i\right|\right].$$ I think the hint is to use a symmetrization argument but I still cannot figure out a way to do it. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Independence of $(X_i)$ with $(Y_i)$ is necessary for the inequality to hold.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks! I have edited the OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result is false as stated (the book is wrong). Namely, let $n=2$, $Y_1 = -5$ and $Y_2 = 5$. However, if the random variables are $Y_i$ are zero-mean, then you can indeed use symmetrization, and it is done in the book in chapter 11. Let $Y_i'$ be an i.i.d. copy of $Y_i$. Then, as done in the book in the proof of lemma 11.4:

\begin{align*}
E|\sum_{i=1}^n X_i Y_i| &= E|\sum_{i=1}^n X_i Y_i - X_i E Y_i'|\\
&\leq E|\sum_{i=1}^n X_i (Y_i - Y_i')|\\
&=E|\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i - Y_i')|\\
&\leq 2 E|\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i|
\end{align*}

Comment: May I know how does the first inequality follows from Jensen's inequality?

Comment: @Fei Cao: by Jensen's inequality, $E\left[|\sum_{i=1}^n X_i(Y_i - Y_i’) | \big| (X_i, Y_i)_{i=1…n}\right]
\geq |\sum_{i=1}^n X_i Y_i - E(Y_i’) |$. The result folllows by taking (unconditional) expectations on both sides.

Comment: Oops, I had a typo; hopefully it is clearer now; the detail of Jensen's is exactly as bdx77 writes.

Comment: @E.A.: except that the RHS of what I wrote should be $|\sum_{i=1}^n X_i(Y_i - E(Y_i'))|$!